# get error list from org.eclipse.jface.text.Document

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I want to get from my document (org.eclipse.jface.text.Document)  or from my plugin workspace the list of the errors that occur on the document which can be found in the Markers view in eclipse , if possible how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a resource reference (`IResource`) and then:

```
resource.findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```